# Parsing JSON with dynamic attributes

Tags: c#, json, .net

i have the following JSON i´m requesting from a service with C# using Newtonsoft.Json

```
[
  {"Example1":value1,
  "Example2":value1,
  "Example3":"value1",
  "ExampleList":
    {"Example4":"",
      "Example5":"value1",
      "Example6":"value1",
      "Example7":"",
      "Example8":"value1"},
  "Example9":["value1"],
  "Example10":[]
  }
]
```

the problem here are the "ExampleList", "Example9" and "Example10".
"ExampleList" list has no defined number of values. it can be 5, in the next query it can be 20.

I already have a similar request, where I only have the ExampleList without the values ​​above it. I solved this with

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

and it works fine.

My question is, how can I combine these two?

I tried something like this i found here [Parsing JSON with dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190670/parsing-json-with-dynamic-properties)

```
public partial class ExampleClass
{
    public int Example1 { get; set; }
    public long Example2 { get; set; }
    public long Example3 { get; set; }
    public ExampleList exampleList { get; set; }
}

public partial class ExampleList
{
    Dictionary<string, string> exampleList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

}
```

Error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Models.ExampleClass' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

**Edit: Guru Strons solution worked. For Example 9 and 10 I created an array.**

```
public class ExampleClass
    {
        public int Example1 { get; set; }
        public int Example2 { get; set; }
        public int Example3 { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> ExampleList { get; set; }
        public string[] Example9 { get; set; }
        public string[] Example10 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
var tempAttr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExampleClass>>(response);
```

Comment: You need to deserialize into `IEnumerable<ExampleClass>` instead of just to `ExampleClass`, because you have a json array of objects

Comment: Or just use JArray.Parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to deserialize dynamically only the `ExampleList` - there is no need to introduce class for it, just make property of type `Dictionary<string, string>()`:

```
public partial class ExampleClass
{
    public int Example1 { get; set; }
    public long Example2 { get; set; }
    public long Example3 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string>() ExampleList { get; set; }
}
```

There is another problem - it seems that you are trying to deserialize to `ExampleClass` but your root json is array, so use `List<ExampleClass>` or another collection type:

```cs
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExampleClass>>(...);
```